# How to manage RTMP Workers / Threads?

Tags: multithreading, weblogic, rtmp, worker, workmanagers

We encounter issues managing how the RTMP workers / threads are allocated to our application server (Weblogic).

It appeared that our server cannot see the threads allocated for the rtmp processes and after a long time the server runs out of available threads. According to Weblogic experts, it's because rtmp workers / threads use default threads on the server.

Using a Weblogic server, we can define some WorkManagers but we did not succeeded in making it work for the rtmp workers / threads.

Do you know any ways to limit the number of rtmp workers / threads allocated ?
Are there any means which could allow our Weblogic application server to manage them through its WorkManagers ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards.